# How to make an DL model predict Correctly

Tags: deep-learning, training, computer-vision, prediction, accuracy

So I trained a DL algorithm using Keras for Human Action Recognition. The model has an accuracy of about 85 percent and a loss of 0.3 something. The problem is that the model did not predict well on unseen data. The dataset consists of 3 classes with 100 videos in each class.

**Training Phase:**
[image: Training of DL model] **The model evaluation** [[image: Model evaluation][2]]

**This was a handwaving video that was predicted as walking**[image: This was a handwaving video that was predicted as walking]
**The model**[image: The model]